# npm run build redhat openshift deploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, openshift, redhat

I have a project built with node.js and react. Every time I build and and deploy, or every time the pod resets, I need to go in to the pod terminal and run 'npm run build' ("build": "react-scripts build"). Is there a way to automate this? (Maybe in my package.json scripts if redhat has specific scripts similar to "heroku-postbuild" or somewhere on the Openshift website?)

Answer (score 1):

If you're building using the Node.js image from the catalog then I'd recommend adding a "postinstall" hook in your package.json to achieve this. This is a standard npm/Node.js supported convention.

Here's an [example repository that demonstrates this](https://github.com/evanshortiss/openshift-typescript-example/blob/master/package.json#L9). Since it uses TypeScript and the TypeScript needs to compile to JavaScript before being run, we define a "postinstall". When OpenShift performs [S2I](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image) to generate a container image for your application it runs npm install (see the source [here](https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/blob/master/8/s2i/bin/assemble#L76)). If you define a "postinstall" hook, this hook can build your application. This means it will always be ready since it becomes part of the container image - even across redeploys.

Note: You will need to move dependencies required to build your application from "dependencies" to "devDependencies" in package.json.